# Contrast ratio between foreground and background

Tags: color, background, contrast

What is an acceptable contrast ratio between a foreground and its background?

Comment: Is this question about websites or printed materials or just generally? I suspect the answer varies by the type of design.

Comment: In what context? It's all about context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If this is for web, I typically use Jonathan Snook's [Color Contrast Checker](http://www.snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html). The safe ratio is about 7.5

Roger Johansson has a nice [blog post](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200709/10_colour_contrast_checking_tools_to_improve_the_accessibility_of_your_design/) about varies contrast checking tool, check it out.

Comment: Not that that is specific to text/background color contrast.